# how to check if object created using scope=prototype is new one and not the old one

Tags: spring, scope, prototype

In Spring, We have scopes as singleton and prototype.
Scope = prototype creates new object every time you do get Bean().
My question is , How can we verify if it is really new object and not the existing one ?

Comment: Not quite ready to trust your framework, huh? Place a breakpoint in the constructor and debug, add logging statement, include a static counter...

Comment: Actually I also would like to get a real statictics about the usage of our prototype-beans as they are more then 400 in our project. And not by only printing the information in console but by some more trustful instruments.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick demonstration.  Bean A is a Prototype bean, Bean B is not.  Each class implements InitializingBean to allow printing to occur if a new object is created.  Then the container will be asked to create each bean twice, and the objects will be compared for equality:

Bean A definition; and Bean B is exactly the same:

```
@Component
public class A implements InitializingBean {

    // ... properties, etc

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Creating A");
    }

}
```

The configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test.config")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public A a() {
        A a = new A();
        return a;
    }

    @Bean
    public B b() {
        B b = new B();
        return b;
    }
}
```

Then use getBean() twice on each bean to test for equality:

```
 A a = (A)ctx.getBean("a"); 
 B b = (B)ctx.getBean("b"); 
 A a2 = (A)ctx.getBean("a");
 B b2 = (B)ctx.getBean("b"); 

 System.out.println("A is a " + (a == a2 ? "Singleton" : "Prototype"));
 System.out.println("B is a " + (b == b2 ? "Singleton" : "Prototype"));
```

And you get the expected outcome, show that A creates a new Object each time getBean() is called, and B does not.

```
Creating A
Creating A
A is a Prototype
B is a Singleton
```